# How can I parse "I’m tired is all"?

Tags: parsing

> I’m tired is all.

How can I parse this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a grammatically correct sentence by itself - usually it would be something like

> "I'm tired" is all [that I want to say].

or

> "I'm tired" is all [that's wrong with me].

It means that there are no major problems; the speaker is just tired, which explains their odd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I am tired. That's all, no more explaination. I guess you were asked by your girlfriend why not pick up the phone.

Comment: I agree that "I'm tired is all" is just a colloquial way of saying, "I'm tired, that's all." It can be hard to parse a colloquialism, which makes this an interesting question. I'm not sure why you think this has anything to do with a girlfriend not picking up the phone, though – that's only one of a myriad of possible scenarios.

Comment: Those are called "jokes," another enigmatic phenomenon...